# How do I find the limit of this specific function

Tags: limits, functions

$$\lim_{x\to-1} \frac{x^2+2x+1}{x+1}$$

It works for some questions, I've tried substituting and factorising, but the correct answer is 0 and I don't know how to get that.

Comment: The limit is not $0$, that is a fact.

Comment: Not 0...book/test/assignment is wrong...

Comment: You don't know how to get that cause that answer is wrong.  The answer is 21 as I assume you figured.  Reread the question.  either you're reading it wrong or the answer key has an indexing error.

Comment: Still not zero.

Comment: The function is defined at 4 so you can just substitute.

Comment: If you change $x\to4$ to $x\to-1$ then (for the current edited version) the answer would indeed be $0$. As long as you know the answer we could always come up with the correct problem :) Perhaps typographically $4$ and $-1$ are easy to confuse. $\lim_{x\to-1} \frac{x^2+2x+1}{x+1}=0$

Comment: Now that you have changed the problem from $\lim_{x\to4}(x^2+5)$ to $\lim_{x\to4}(x^2+2x+\frac{1}{x}+1)$ the answer is $25.25$.

Comment: The function is continuous and defined at x = 4 so you can do a simple substitution.  The answer is 5.  More to the point would be it x goes to -1 where the function is *not* defined and the limit *is* 0.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is indeed $0$, subject to a couple of minor corrections to the problem.

First it shouldn't be $\lim_{x\to4} x^2+2x+1/x+1$ but 
$\lim_{x\to4} (x^2+2x+1)/(x+1)$, that is 
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to4} \frac{x^2+2x+1}{x+1}$.

Second, $4$ is not $4$ but $-1$. Perhaps that was a typo, $4$ and $-1$ may look similar. So it should be $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to-1} \frac{x^2+2x+1}{x+1}= \lim_{x\to-1} \frac{(x+1)^2}{x+1}=\lim_{x\to-1} x+1=-1+1=0$.

Never worry about the answer, we could always change the question to match it.